# Same Page SubNav on multiple pages website

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, anchor, submenu

i'm trying to change the css of an anchor included in a `<li>` of a submenu. Here is the HTML :

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li class="subnav current"><a href="page1.html">Page1</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="page1.html#section1a">Page 1 Section A</a></li>
         <li><a href="page1.html#section1b">Page 1 Section B</a></li>
         <li><a href="page1.html#section1c">Page 1 Section C</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="subnav"><a href="page2.html">Page2</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="page2.html#section2a">Page 2 Section A</a></li>
         <li><a href="page2.html#section2b">Page 2 Section B</a></li>
         <li><a href="page2.html#section2c">Page 2 Section C</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
<ul>
```

Each section has a 1060px width, a left float, and all the sections are included in a div container which overflow is hidden.
Here is the script i tried :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var P=($(".section").position().left)*-1
   var N=(P/1060)+1
   $("#nav li.current ul li:first-child").find("a").css("color","#e53f33");
   $("#nav li.current ul li:nth-child(N)").click(function(){
      $(this).siblings().find("a").css("color","#777777");
      $(this).find("a").css("color","#e53f33");
   });
});
```

This script works fine when i stay on the same page. But, i.e., when i'm in page 1 and click a link located in page 2, the first-child's css is changed, even if i clicked on another child. Where is my mistake?

> You can see whats happening here http://www.theworkingowl.com.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, why wouldn't you put the click events on the anchors?  Also, the nth-child approach is not what you want here. Have you thought about applying/removing classes instead?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // take care of direct hash links...
   var relative_url = window.location.href.substr(window.location.protocol.length+window.location.hostname.length+3);
   $('a[href="'+relative_url+'"]').addClass('current').parent().siblings().find('a').css('color', '#777');

   // take care of clicks that stay on this page...
   $('#nav a').click(function() {
     $(this).parent().addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
   });
});
```

And then your CSS...

```
#nav a { color:#777777; }
#nav li.current a { color:#e53f33; }
```

Comment: Hello, Landons, thanks very much for your answer. Adding or removing a class is indeed a good solution when you stay in the same page. But when you click a link in an other page, ie section 2B, that's section's link anchor wont be added a class (because you didn't click on any link in this new page).

Comment: Is it all static html, or are you generating it with server-side scripts? If it's static, try adding this: $(function() { $('a[href="'+window.location.pathname+'"]').parents('li').addClass('current'); }); to the bottom of the page...

Comment: It's all static html; i tried what you adviced, but its not working, i don't see why. I tried this too : `var url = window.location.href; if (url.search("#section1b")>0){$("#nav li a[href*=#section1b]").addClass("current");}` but its not working too...